# What's the neatest way of writing assignments in Python?

Tags: python

I've got lots of these types of things in my code; they make the file super long and boring. Is there a nice way to shorten it?

```
def __init__(self):
  self.g = []
  self.t = []
  self.d = []
  self.fft = []
  self.freq = []
```

Comment: Maybe: `self.g, self.t, self.d = [], [], []`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some options:

```
    def __init__(self):
        for att in ('g','t','d','fft','freq'):
            setattr(self,att,[])
```

or

```
def __init__(self):
    attrs = ('g','t','d','fft','freq')
    self.__dict__.update(zip(attrs,([] for _ in range(len(attrs)))))
```

But honestly?  The explicit method is fine.  I suppose this method gets better when you have some unwieldy number of attributes (10+ maybe) but in that case I'd reexamine whether you can package some of them together into their own collection.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can also do:

```
def __init__(self):
  self.g, self.t, self.d, self.fft, self.freq = [], [], [], [], []
```

That's shorter but I'm not sure it's really better...

Comment: it's definitely better- the file is long and there's a lot of scrolling, even removing a few lines is a lot of help- thank you!

Comment: It's definitely not better, this will make for unreadable code

Comment: How readable does a series of empty list initializations need to be? Unit tests should ensure that that are initialized properly. (Just to play devil's advocate; I would probably stick with the code in the original question as well.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
def __init__(self):
    attr_names = ['g', 't', 'd', 'fft', 'freq']
    for attr_name in attr_names:
        setattr(self, attr_name, [])
```

But if you set object attributes in this way the code will be too *dynamic* and if IDE or other static analyzer used then it can't give good results.

Answer (score 0):

## Use `this` module

```
$ python -m this|grep Readability
Readability counts
```

Your code snippet seems to me the neatest way to do what you need.